# Django- Using Parameters To Display Entry

Tags: python, django

My database is setup something like.

```
class comments(models.Model):
    min = models.FloatField()
    max = models.FloatField()
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

In my view, I grab a float value from the user. I want to take that value use the Min/Max as parameters and if that float value is between the Min/Max, display the comment that's associated to it. At times there might be more then 1 match, however for now I cant even figure out how to do the first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`filter()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#filter) method of a model manager with a combination of [`__lte`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#lte)/[`__gte`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#gte) lookups:

```
def comments(request):
    value = float(request.GET['value'])
    return render(request, 'comments.html',
                 {'comments': comments.objects.filter(min__lte=value,
                                                      max__gte=value)})
```

And then in the `comments.html`:

```
{% for comment in comments %}
    <div>{{ comment.comment }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks! It was the __lte/__gte I needed.